# $H^2$ regularity for divergence style right hand side.

Tags: partial-differential-equations, regularity-theory-of-pdes

Let $u\in H^1(\Omega)$ satisfy $$\int_\Omega (A\nabla u)\cdot\nabla v\,dx=\int_\Omega g\cdot \nabla v\,dx\,\,\forall v\in H^1_0(\Omega)$$ where $g\in L^2(\Omega;\Bbb R^2)$, $A\in W^{1,\infty}(\Omega;\Bbb R^{2\times 2})$, $\Omega\subset\Bbb R^2$ bounded with sufficiently smooth boundary, can we show that $u\in H^2_{\operatorname{Loc}}(\Omega)$?

Comment: I can't parse the integrand on the left-hand side. I assume you mean that $d=2$ so that $A$ is $\mathbb R^{2 \times 2}$-valued, but how then is $A \nabla u \nabla v$ defined?

Comment: @UmbertoP. Sorry, I have edited, $A$ is $\Bbb R^{2\times 2}$ valued

Comment: Thanks, but it's still not clear how the integrand is defined. What is $A \nabla u$?

Comment: $A\nabla u$ is a vector, $A$ is a matrix, and $\nabla u$ is a vector, in summation $(A\nabla u)\cdot\nabla v=\sum_{i,j=1}^2A_{ij}\partial_iu\partial_jv$

Comment: OK, and by hypothesis each $A_{ij} \in W^{1,\infty}(\Omega)$.

Comment: @UmbertoP. yup :) I know standardly, if instead the right hand side was just $f\in L^2(\Omega)$, then we could test with $v = -\Delta^{-h}_k(\varphi^2\Delta^h_k u)$ where $\Delta^h_k$ is the difference quotient, and $\varphi$ is a smooth cut off function, we can bound things and gain local $H^2$ regularity, but not too sure what to do in the current case..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your equation is $-\text{div} (A \nabla u)= \text{div} g$. The heuristic is that since $\nabla u$ and $g$ have the same 'strength' in the equation, $\nabla u$ will have the same regularity as $g$. In other words $H^ 1$ is as best as you can hope (at lest in these simple spaces).

As an example take $g\in L^ 2 \setminus H^ 1$, then the solution of $-\Delta u = \text{div}g \in H^{-1}\setminus L^2$ clearly has $u\notin H^ 2$.